# Laravel 5.2 Checking user field on login

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have spent all day trying to find the best practice solution for this.
I want to check if the boolean field in the user table is true before letting the user see any other pages.

I am using Laravels built in auth and I have tried many solutions that are already on stack overflow and they dont work.

Comment: what does the field signify?

Comment: Also, you should use the `Auth` middleware to do this. then you can just access the field like this: `Auth::user()->myField` and then use an if statement to determine if the value is true or not and what to do next.

Comment: boolean 0 false 1 true, named email_activated for email activations

Comment: So just put the Auth check on every controller im wanting to protect?

Comment: Nope, just the Auth middleware

Comment: I was writing a answer suggesting @OliverQueen's suggestion. But now does not have sense xD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a middleware. Something like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use Redirect;

class UserHasField
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->field === 0)
            return redirect()->route('named.route');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Now add your middleware class to `kernel.php` (in http) folder:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'user_has' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserHasField::class,
];
```

Now use it in your routes for example:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['user_has']], function () {
   ...
});
```

Comment: you sir.. thank you... I have even been trying to edit the actual login process when its this easy...

Comment: No prob! It's pretty easy one you know it.

Answer (score 1):

Oliver Queen has the correct/best practice and purpose of Laravel 5.0.

The concept of Middleware (as Jeffrey Way puts it), is like an onion. Its purpose is "before you hit the controller" what do you want to do. Auth itself is a middleware service just like validation.

all you need to do is construct your extra middleware logic code to extract the extra check on that field and accept/reject if present.

Now you have stated "i have to code this against all controller?" no that is the beauty of middleware, you can use them as part of a group.

Check Matt Stauffer's explanation:
https://mattstauffer.co/blog/middleware-groups-in-laravel-5-2

Comment: Ok that sounds a lot better. Does anyone here have an example of their edits to an auth controller?

Comment: @Unifx go to the site I mentioned, and it shows you how to use middleware

Comment: yeah this is for 5.0 not 5.2 now it uses middleware groups and the base is set at web, I do not wish to change the group only edit it and I am just trying to find where this group exists.

Comment: @Unifx there, I have linked to 5.2 updated, if you hit blog it was the 6-7th article